# Batch Delete excluding files under specific folder (or file names with specific pattern /wildcard e.g. Test123.csv, Test623.csv, Test854.csv)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
FORFILES /P "C:\Temp\" /D -3 /S /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del /F /Q @path"
```

above script is working fine and delete all files under Temp and its subdirectory older than 3 days.

I want to exclude all files from specific folder say all files from folder XYZ or full path-> `C:\Temp\ABC\XYZ`

Note : all files under `XYZ` folders are having pattern say `Test*.*.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forfiles` does not have an exclude option. You have to use something like `findstr /V` to exclude the results, but that will not form part of the `forfiles` command in itself. We simply incorporate a `for` loop and ecxlude using `findstr /V`, then delete:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FORFILES /P "%temp%" /D -3 /S /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @path"^| findstr /VI "C:\Temp\ABC\XYZ"') do del /F /Q "%%~i"
```

Comment: Thanks Gerhard.  This syntax is unable to delete file if it contains space in it's name  e.g. ABC_20211101 (2).csv.   it is trying to locate file like "C:\Temp\ABC_20211101"   & "(2).csv" separately.

Comment: show me the exact code you're running, please.

Comment: oh, also found a typo my side, end of the command `"%%i~"` should be `"%%~i"`

Comment: Thanks Gerhard  changing final argument to "%%~i"  worked.